# Push to iPhone with c#

Tags: c#, iphone, ipad

I want to send push notifications to iPhones using c#. I currently use apns-sharp but I'm not really satisfied with that...

Does somebody knows a good way to do this? Keep in mind we have to send many push notifications to many iphones in a short period. So the method has to be quick.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok use the apns-sharp but be awere that there are some issues with it. It can take some time to get it fully working... After you adjusted the issues you are facing it works fine...